# psql: FATAL: role "-h" does not exist

Tags: bash, postgresql, centos7, psql

I have been searching for this issue online and none of the answers clarify my question.

Here is my issue:

I am trying to run .sql files using one of the scripts(abc.sh) in Centos(SSH). These .sql files runs the select commands on postgreSQL and retrieve the data into a file. However, when I am trying to run the script(abc.sh) I see an error thrown on console as below

```
-bash: line 2: <**environment-file-path**>: Permission denied
psql: FATAL:  role "-h" does not exist
```

The error is occurred on the line

```
. /<env_file_path>/yyy.env
export PGPASSWORD=$PGPASSWORD | psql -U $PGUSERNAME $PGNAME -h $PGHOST -c "SET search_path TO xxx;COPY (select....,
```

I am really not sure what is causing the issue here as i did whatever can be done from my end.
1. I have executed the same scripts in different environment with different host and user credentials and it worked.
2. I have changed the pg_hba.conf file i.e. I made it to look alike as of the environment in which the scripts ran successfully.

NOTE: I have an environment file which stores all the useful information and parameters for the above variables(second snippet) are passed from this env file.

Even after doing this stuff i don't see any change on the issue. Hopefully, this is a minor issue and can be fixed easily with someone's help.

Comment: Try putting your variables in double quotes.  Are they all set?

Comment: codeforester is correct. You do not have all your variables set. psql sees `-U -h` and knows that `-h` is not a role.

Comment: I understand. But is it possible to set the variables in .sql files by calling env file from it? as i don't want to directly write the sensitive info on .sql files

Comment: The error message occurs because neither `PGUSERNAME` nor `$PGNAME` are defined; the unquoted expansions simply "disappear", leaving `-h` as the argument for `-U`. Also, `export` doesn't work like that.

Comment: Putting the password in the environment is only marginally better than putting it in a file.

Comment: (There isn't actually any way to store the password in the evironment, though; you need to use a `.pgpass` file.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the file `/<env_file_path>/yyy.env` readable
It looks like the directory that contains that file is missing execute permission. execute is needed to read files in that directory.

but there's some really bad shell scripting there... **always use quotes around variables**.
also don't pipe export.

```
export PGPASSWORD="$PGPASSWORD" 
psql -U "$PGUSERNAME" "$PGNAME" -h "$PGHOST" -c "SET search_path TO xxx;COPY (select....,  "
```

Now you will get a more sensible error message when you forget to set `$PGNAME`.

Always use quotes, if you come across a use case for not having quotes you should probably be using an array there (and still using quotes).